# Set Web app to always open in desktop mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need help setting my react web app to always open on desktop mode when a user tries accessing it from a mobile device. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 2):

You probably could set a minimal width for your web page container via CSS, for example:

```css
body {
  min-width: 960px;
}
```